# Disable Symbol scanner 'beep' on successful scan?

Tags: c#, compact-framework, barcode-scanner, motorola

I'm working with a motorolla MC55 which scans and beeps on a successful scan, I need to disable that feature so that it doesn't play any sounds at all on a scan.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: If it's anything like any of the other Motorola / Symbol barcode scanners, it very likely comes with a manual containing a sheet of special configuration barcodes, one of which controls both the volume and the nature of the beeps.

Comment: I have to do it in code somewhere...

Comment: So far I haven't seen any mobile device that could be configured using barcodes. This is only possible (and required) for "dumb" gun scanners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Symbol.Barcode.Reader reader = new Symbol.Barcode.Reader();

// Other initialization 

reader.Parameters.Feedback.Success.BeepTime = 0;
```

Comment: I know it has been a while but where does this code run and is there a documented api?

Comment: Yes, the .NET API also comes with a documentation and sample code that will make pretty clear how to implement this.

Answer (score 7):

Scan the following barcodes to enable/disable the beep.

[image: Reference Page]

Comment: The MC55 is a mobile device, while the LS2208 is a gun scanner. This manual is not applicable to the MC55.

Comment: This worked with my Symbol DS9208 too! This wasn't in the manual so glad to find a solution here!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to just adjust the level of the sound:

```
Symbol.Audio.Device MyDevice = (Symbol.Audio.Device)Symbol.StandardForms.SelectDevice.Select(
    Symbol.Audio.Controller.Title,
    Symbol.Audio.Device.AvailableDevices);
Symbol.Audio.StandardAudio MyAudioDevice = new Symbol.Audio.StandardAudio(MyDevice);

// set the volume of the audio from the settings file.
MyAudioDevice.BeeperVolume = NewLevel;

// set the audio device to nothing
MyAudioDevice.Dispose();
MyAudioDevice = null;
MyDevice = null;
```